# mat-tab in dynamic component doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to create component each time there is a user click on a button.
In this created component, I have some DOM which include **mat-tab-group** with two **mat-tab**. Unfortunately the second tab content is empty and the switch between the two tabs doesn't work.

Here is how I create the component in the parent one (lets say **MapComponent.ts**) :

```js
private createComponent(): IInfoWindowComponent {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(IInfoWindowComponent);
    const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    return ref.instance;
}
```

Here is my dynamic component view (**IInfoWindowComponent.html**) :

```html
    <mat-tab-group (selectChange)="toggleSomething()">
        <mat-tab label="Résumé" id="sumup-tab">
            <p>wow what a tab!</p>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Logistique" id="logistique-tab">
            <p>Hi there!</p>
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

The thing is that on a different view , i'm using material tabs without problems. That's why I'm pretty sure this behavior is due to the dynamic component creation... But any idea how I could fix this ?

Comment: How are these two pieces of code related ? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @n00dl3 sorry I thought it was clear enough. Just edited my post to add component titles

Comment: Is it giving you any errors? I'm not completely sure but if I recall dynamic components also need to be in `entryComponents` in your module.